Derivative of a composite function where the inner function is the inverse of a known function
Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
$$y=f(x,\theta)$$
which is continuous and invertible once $\theta$ is fixed
$f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
$$x=f^{-1}(y,\theta)$$
Suppose we have another function $g:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
$$z=g(x,\theta)$$ and we want to compute
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}g(f^{-1}(y,\theta),\theta)$$
and evaluate it over different values of y.
Is it possible to evaluate this derivative without explicitly determining $f^{-1}$?

Can you write your functions down carefully? Like, explicitly say their domain, codomain, and properties you are assuming?

@Malady I assume they are at least C1 and invertibility between x and y

How can $f$ be invertible? You seem not to understand what that actually means. You need to rewrite this completely and with great care.

@TedShifrin you are right. In my case it is invertible when $\theta$ is held fixed. I updated the text.

No, writing $f^{-1}$ is completely incorrect. You must introduce a function $x=h(y,\theta)$ with $y=f(h(x,\theta),\theta)$.

I think it is possible by using the chain rule, my attempt:
Let's take it as $x=f^{-1}(y,θ)$. That is exactly to say, $y=f(x,θ)$. we need to find the derivative of $g(x, θ)$ with regard to $θ$.
Therefore, the chain rule is involved:
$$d(g(x, θ))/dθ = (∂g/∂x)(dx/dθ) + ∂g/∂θ$$
We cannot ascertain $dx/dθ$ directly, yet, as $y$= $f(x, θ)$, we can now differentiate the right side with respect to $θ$ (remembering that $x$ is dependent on $θ$):
$$dy/dθ = (∂f/∂x)(dx/dθ) + ∂f/∂θ$$
We regard $y$ as a constant in differentiation concerning $θ$ so $dy/dθ$ = 0, therefore:
$0 = (∂f/∂x)(dx/dθ) + ∂f/∂θ$
now just solve for the derivative of $x$ with respect to $θ$:
$$dx/dθ = -(∂f/∂θ) / (∂f/∂x)$$
This should be done by $(∂f/∂x)$ plugging back into the chain rule for $d(g(x,θ))/dθ$:
$$d(g(x, θ))/dθ = (∂g/∂x)[- (∂f/∂θ) / (∂f/∂x)] + ∂g/∂θ$$
Thus, the formulation is, you are only supposed to solve the partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$ with respect to $x$ and $θ$, respectively, at the position $(x, θ)$. $x$ is defined hence $y$ = $f(x, θ)$). You don't need to find $f^{-1}$ obviously.

Thank you, this is it. Notice that I still need $f^{-1}$ because $∂g/∂x$
contains terms in x. In my particular case performing the evaluation after the derivative computation is however much better,  so this is nonetheless a big step forward!
